# SQL-Update Table from table variable does not fire the update trigger

Tags: t-sql, variables, sql-update, database-trigger

Problem Solved, thank you all so much.
Seems likethe if not update() is excluding all updates that contain column "Sync" while my initial intent was trying to exclude updates only on that column.

I've created an update trigger to audit any updates happen to a table.
And I just realized if I update from a variable, it would not fire the trigger. Is there a solution to solve this?

The Trigger:

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[update_trigger]
On [dbo].[material_current]
For Update
as
if NOT UPDATE(SyncP6)
begin
INSERT INTO [dbo].[material_audit]
           ([ID_SAP_Project],[ID_SAP_Material],[Order_Date],[Delivery_date],[Expected_Delivery_Date]
           ,[SignedBy],[Need_Date][material_Location],[Operation])
    SELECT [ID_SAP_Project],[ID_SAP_Material],[Order_Date],[Delivery_date],[Expected_Delivery_Date]
          ,[SignedBy],[Need_Date],[material_Location],'UI'
           FROM inserted;
END;
GO
```

The Update Query

```
DECLARE @t_updates table ([Row] int IDENTITY(1,1), [ID_SAP_Project] [nvarchar](15), [ID_SAP_Material] [int], [Order_Date] [date], [Delivery_date] [date], [material_Location] [nvarchar](max))

INSERT INTO @t_updates 
Values ('1H341J123',520034,'2017-11-10','2017-12-14','WH2 - Area C')

UPDATE [material_current]
SET [Order_Date] = (SELECT [Order_Date] FROM @t_updates WHERE [Row] = 1), [Delivery_date] = (SELECT [Delivery_date] FROM @t_updates WHERE [Row] = 1),
    [material_Location] = (SELECT [material_Location] FROM @t_updates WHERE [Row] = 1)
WHERE [ID_SAP_Project] = (SELECT [ID_SAP_Project] FROM @t_updates WHERE [Row] = 1) AND [ID_SAP_Material] = (SELECT [ID_SAP_Material] FROM @t_updates WHERE [Row] = 1)
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? That code is product specific.

Comment: @jarlh I'm using SQL Management Studio 17.2

Comment: What are you seeing that makes you think the trigger doesn't fire?   Keep in mind your trigger has this line:  `if NOT UPDATE(SyncP6)`

Comment: @TabAllemanI think that's it! thank you so much, I put that if trying to exclude when the update is only on that column, but turns out it's excluding any updates that's contain that column.